# How to modify a structured numpy arrray using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, pybind11

I've got a few structs

```
/* Ray structure for a single ray */
struct RTC_ALIGN(16) RTCRay
{
  float org_x;        // x coordinate of ray origin
  float org_y;        // y coordinate of ray origin
  float org_z;        // z coordinate of ray origin
  float tnear;        // start of ray segment

  float dir_x;        // x coordinate of ray direction
  float dir_y;        // y coordinate of ray direction
  float dir_z;        // z coordinate of ray direction
  float time;         // time of this ray for motion blur

  float tfar;         // end of ray segment (set to hit distance)
  unsigned int mask;  // ray mask
  unsigned int id;    // ray ID
  unsigned int flags; // ray flags
};

/* Hit structure for a single ray */
struct RTC_ALIGN(16) RTCHit
{
  float Ng_x;          // x coordinate of geometry normal
  float Ng_y;          // y coordinate of geometry normal
  float Ng_z;          // z coordinate of geometry normal

  float u;             // barycentric u coordinate of hit
  float v;             // barycentric v coordinate of hit

  unsigned int primID; // primitive ID
  unsigned int geomID; // geometry ID
  unsigned int instID[1]; // instance ID
  unsigned int instPrimID[1]; // instance primitive ID
};

/* Combined ray/hit structure for a single ray */
struct RTCRayHit
{
  struct RTCRay ray;
  struct RTCHit hit;
};
```

And I have defined the datatypes using pybind11

```
    PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(RTCRay, org_x, org_y, org_z, tnear, dir_x, dir_y, dir_z, time, tfar, mask, id, flags);
    PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(RTCHit, Ng_x, Ng_y, Ng_z, u, v, primID, geomID, instID, instPrimID);
    PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(RTCRayHit, ray, hit);
```

So that I can pass in a structured numpy array to this function

```
void ray_intersect(py::array_t<RTCRayHit, py::array::c_style>& rays) {
    auto buf = rays.request();
    RTCRayHit* ptr = static_cast<RTCRayHit*>(buf.ptr);
    std::cout << ptr[0].ray.org_x << std::endl;
    ptr->ray.org_x = 2.0;
    ptr[0].ray.org_x = 2.0;
    std::cout << ptr[0].ray.org_x << std::endl;
}
```

allowing me to call the code from python

```
RTC_MAX_INSTANCE_LEVEL_COUNT = 1

dt_ray = np.dtype([
    ('org_x', 'f4'), ('org_y', 'f4'), ('org_z', 'f4'), ('tnear', 'f4'),
    ('dir_x', 'f4'), ('dir_y', 'f4'), ('dir_z', 'f4'), ('time', 'f4'),
    ('tfar', 'f4'), ('mask', 'u4'), ('id', 'u4'), ('flags', 'u4')
])

# Define the RTCHit structure
dt_hit = np.dtype([
    ('Ng_x', 'f4'), ('Ng_y', 'f4'), ('Ng_z', 'f4'),
    ('u', 'f4'), ('v', 'f4'),
    ('primID', 'u4'), ('geomID', 'u4'),
    ('instID', ('u4', (RTC_MAX_INSTANCE_LEVEL_COUNT,))),
    ('instPrimID', ('u4', (RTC_MAX_INSTANCE_LEVEL_COUNT,)))
])

# Define the RTCRayHit structure
dt_rayhit = np.dtype([
    ('ray', dt_ray),
    ('hit', dt_hit)
])

rayhit = np.zeros(1, dtype=dt_rayhit)
rayhit[0]["ray"]["org_x"] = 1.0
print(rayhit)
ray_intersect(rayhit)
print(rayhit)
```

The numpy array seems to be succesfully passed to the ray_intersect function since it prints "1", the original rays[0].ray.x_org then "2" the modified one but then when we get back into python code the rayhit array appears unchanged.

The output looks like:

```
[((1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0, 0), (0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0, [0], [0]))]
1
2
[((1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0, 0), (0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0, [0], [0]))]
```

I feel like I may have specified the struct improperly to pybind11 and its silently copying it which means my mutation of rays[0].ray.org_x has no effect.

Comment: After playing around with the code a bit more, I've discovered that its the alignment. Since the Ray and Hit structs are Align(16) they dont line up with the structured array.